# Android-fragment не исчезает главный фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment

Делаю приложение с несколькими фрагмента. На первом фрагменте несколько кнопок, если перейти на второй фрагмент, то кнопки с первого фрагмента видны. Я задал фон для второго фрагмента, кнопки не видны, но если кликнуть туда где они были, то все равно доступны и происходит их вызов, подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Покажите код смены фрагментов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте корневому лейауту второго фрагмента (тому, у которого вы добавили фон) параметр `android:clickable="true"`. Он будет перехватывать нажатия и они не пойдут ниже.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы унаследовали фрагменты из разных пакетов. У них методы смены фрагмента происходят по разному. Вам нужно либо унаследовать фрагменты от одного родителя, либо сначало удалить с экрана старый фрагмент , а потом добавлять новый

Answer (score 0):

Такое поведение происходит когда добавляете фрагмент через add, если же добавлять через replace, то обрабатывать нажатие второой вью не требуется